# Linear ODEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, eigenvalues

I am trying to solve some first order linear odes. My code is below:

```
eq={1. j1[z] + 
   10. u1[z] + (-0.04 - 0.02 λ[z]) w0[z] + 0.02 w1'[z] == 0,
   (1.68333 + λ[z] (2. + 1. λ[z])) u0[z] + λ[z] ((2. - 0.5 λ[z]) u2[z] - 
      250. w1[z] - 25. ϕ0[z] + 25. ϕ1[z] + 0.5 u3'[z]) == 0, 
   100 u1[z] + ϕ1'[z] == 50 u3[z] + (2 + λ[z]) ϕ0[z],
   (2 + λ[z]) j0[z] == 50 w1[z] + j1'[z], 
   u1[z] == u0'[z], u2[z] == u1'[z], u3[z] == u2'[z], 
   ϕ1[z] == ϕ0'[z], w1[z] == w0'[z], j1[z] == j0'[z]};

eqns = Rationalize[{eq, u0[0] == 0, u0[1] == 0, 
   u1[0]== 0, u1[1]== 0, w0[0] == 0, w0[1] == 0, 
   j1[0] == 0, j1[1] == 0, ϕ0[0] == 0, 
   ϕ0[1] == 0, λ'[z] == 0, u2[1] == 0}];

sol1 = NDSolve[
  eqns, {u0, w0, λ}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {λ[0] == 20+ I}, 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}
  }(*, AccuracyGoal -> 10,PrecisionGoal -> 10*)
 ];

{λ[0] /. sol1}
```

There are 10 homogeneous equations and related 10 homogeneous boundary conditions. It is going to be an eigenvalue problem. For reasons unknown to me, the method doesn't converge. How can see where I'm going wrong while using the NDSolve? Are there any other ways to solve it. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I get some errors related to initial conditions. Have you tried other methods instead of the shooting method? Particularly, have you tried not specifying a method and letting `NDSolve` choose?

Comment: Consider also rewriting your equations completely to get rid of the Subscript expressions. They are a pretty-printing construct that sometimes cause misbehavior that is hard to track down.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you. I have corrected the mistake. Yes, I meant eqns. I haven't tried it without giving a method.

Comment: @MarcoB I have made the changes.

Comment: Do you mean *nonlinear* instead of linear? (Technically the system is not homogenous. To be homogenous, all terms should have the same degree. At a glance, I see degree-1 and degree-2 terms. When a system is linear, the textbooks tend to emphasize the absence of a term without a dependent variable, which means all the terms present are degree-1.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 For a given lambda those equations are coupled linear equations without a forcing term.

Comment: Ah, as I said, at a glance (which was on a phone). My mistake. Sorry for the trouble. I was also thrown off by asking `NDSolve` to solve for a variable it turns out you specify. I mistook that to mean lambda was a variable: Technically it is nonlinear because of how the code is set up, and the system probably won't be classified as linear because of it. But treating `λ[z]` as a constant parameter, isn't the trivial (zero) solution the only solution to the BVP above?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The problem can be setup as an eigenvalue problem. NDSolve can find the eigenvalues for non-trivial solutions when you give an extra-condition and treat the eigenvalue (in my case lambda) as a dependent variable. In my case, I have given u2[1]=0.

Comment: Solving for the eigenvalue is not what `NDSolve` did in the only answer at the time, which produced in effect the zero solution for the given λ. @bbgodfrey's answer illustrates how I thought the problem would be set up, although it doesn't seem to finish the problem. I was going to use `MatrixExp`, mainly because I was led to analyze the need for 32 dig. of precision in the first answer. The numerical trouble makes me think numerical sols. for eigenvalues should be verified. Also the `20 + I` for λ  led me away from treating it as a real-only problem as in the accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Would you please share here as a code of what you want to do with the problem?

Comment: If λ is a constant and not a function of z, then it gives the same solution as DSolve (see @bbgodfrey's answer). Basically if $X'(z) = A.X(z)$, where $X$ is the vector of dependent variables (not including λ) and $A=A(\lambda)$ is the matrix of coefficients of your system (containing λ as shown in coefficients of `eq`). Then the solution $X(z)$ with initial condition vector `x0` at `z=0` is given by `MatrixExp[A * z].x0` (or `MatrixExp[A * z, x0]`). The values at the other boundary `z=1` are given by `MatrixExp[A * 1, x0]`. Use your BCs to determine `x0` and λ, I suppose, but it's really slow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This eigenvalue problem can be solved largely symbolically as follows.  With the equations rationalized,

```
eq = {j1[z] + 10 u1[z] + w0[z] (-(1/25) - λ[z]/50) + w1'[z]/50 == 0, 
  u0[z] (168333/100000 + λ[z] (2 + λ[z])) + λ[z] (-250 w1[z] + 
    u2[z] (2 - λ[z]/2) - 25 ϕ0[z] + 25 ϕ1[z] + u3'[z]/2) == 0, 
  100 u1[z] + ϕ1'[z] == 50 u3[z] + (2 + λ[z]) ϕ0[z], 
  j0[z] (2 + λ[z]) == 50 w1[z] + j1[z], 
  u1[z] == u0'[z], u2[z] == u1'[z], u3[z] == u2'[z], 
  ϕ1[z] == ϕ0'[z], w1[z] == w0'[z], j1[z] == j0'[z]};
```

solve them symbolically with only the boundary conditions at `z = 0` specified.

```
sol = DSolve[{eq /. λ[z] -> λ, 
  u0[0] == 0, u1[0] == 0, w0[0] == 0, j1[0] == 0, ϕ0[0] == 0}, 
  {j0[z], j1[z], u0[z], u1[z], u2[z], u3[z], w0[z], w1[z], ϕ0[z], ϕ1[z]}, 
  z] // Flatten
```

The solution is enormous and cannot be reproduced here.  Nonetheless, the eigenvalues can be extracted by applying the `z = 1` boundary conditions and constructing the array of coefficients of the five remaining constants of integration.

```
{u0[z], u1[z], w0[z], j1[z], ϕ0[z]} /. sol /. z -> 1;
co = Last@CoefficientArrays[%, {C[1], C[5], C[6], C[8], C[10]}] // Normal
```

Now, plot the determinant of this array as a function of `λ` to obtain estimates of the first several eigenvalues.

```
Plot[10^-15 Det[co], {λ, -500, 500}, PlotRange -> {-50, 50}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {λ, "Det"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The first seven (in absolute value) are

```
N@FindRoot[10^-15 Det[co], {λ, -2.1, -1.9}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, Evaluated -> False, Method -> "Brent"]
(* {λ -> -2.00116} *)
```

and, similarly,

```
(* {λ -> -15.3281} *)
(* {λ -> -35.2267} *)
(* {λ -> 110.078} *)
(* {λ -> 148.461} *)
(* {λ -> -201.539} *)
(* {λ -> -225.151} *)
```

**Addendum: Numerical Solution**

The procedure just described works only for ODEs that can be solved using `DSolve`.  The OP asked in a comment how to obtain eigenvalues for ODEs that can be solved only with `NDSolve`.  The following works well.

The symbolic solution given above in effect seeks a linear combination of five independent solutions that satisfy the five boundary conditions at `z = 1`.  This is possible only if the determinant of the coefficient matrix of those five solutions at `z = 1` vanishes.  That occurs only for isolated values of `λ`, determined using `FindRoot`.  A similar process is feasible for numerical solutions.  Obtain five linearly independent solutions satisfying the `z = 0` boundary conditions by setting four of the other five dependent variables, `{u2[z], u3[z], w1[z], j0[z], ϕ1[z]}` to `0` there, and the other equal to `1`. Then the corresponding values of `{u0[z], u1[z], w0[z], j1[z], ϕ0[z]}` comprise the rows of the coefficient matrix.  For convenience, define

```
var = {u0[z], u1[z], w0[z], j1[z], ϕ0[z], u2[z], u3[z], w1[z], j0[z], ϕ1[z]};
```

Then the determinant of the coefficient matrix is given by

```
g[λt_] := Module[{v = Rationalize[λt, 0]}, Do[
  bc0 = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, 10], n + 5 -> 1];
  a[n] = NDSolveValue[{eq /. λ[z] -> v, Thread[(var /. z -> 0) == bc0]}, 
    var[[;; 5]] /. z -> 1, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {n, 5}];
-10^-15 Det[{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]}]]
```

Plotting this function

```
Plot[g[λ], {λ, -500, 500}, PlotRange -> {-45, 45}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 1, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {λ, "Det"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

yields a figure indistinguishable to the eye from the plot given above, and the first seven eigenvalues are the same to five significant figures (except for the first eigenvalue which is the same only to three significant figures).

**Second Addendum: Eigenfunctions**

For completeness, corresponding eigenfunctions can be computed numerically without difficulty.  With `g` defined as above but with `WorkingPrecision -> 55` and `MaxSteps -> 50000`, compute the desired eigenvalue to greater accuracy, for instance,

```
tst = λ /. FindRoot[g[λ], {λ, -17, -15}, WorkingPrecision -> 55, 
    Evaluated -> False, Method -> "Brent"]
(* -15.328093316320908139126966813678620281397158355749 *)
```

Because the determinant of the coefficient matrix determined by `g` vanishes to high order, the coefficient matrix has a null space vector, which can be used as follows to determine the eigenfunctions.

```
NullSpace[Transpose[{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]}]] // Flatten;
bc0 = Join[ConstantArray[0, 5], Rationalize[%, 0]];
NDSolveValue[{eq /. λ[z] -> Rationalize[tst, 0], Thread[(var /. z -> 0) == bc0]}, 
    var, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 55];
```

Plots of the eigenfunction, first for the components with homogeneous boundary conditions and then for those with unspecified boundary conditions, are

```
Plot[Evaluate[%[[;; 5]]], {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Head /@ var[[;; 5]], 
        LegendLayout -> "Row"], {.7, .1}]]
Plot[Evaluate[%%[[6 ;;]]], {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Head /@ var[[6 ;;]], 
        LegendLayout -> "Row"], {.7, .1}]]
```

[image]

[image]

The accuracy with which the `z = 1` boundary conditions are satisfied is

```
N[%%%[[;; 5]] /. z -> 1]
(* {1.06179*10^-10, 5.22517*10^-9, 5.09433*10^-8, -2.53322*10^-6, 2.59614*10^-7} *)
```

Incidentally, by inspection the smallest eigenvalue (in absolute value) is exactly `λ = -2`, and the corresponding eigenfunction is `j0[z]` a non-zero constant, and all other dependent variables identically zero.

**Third Addendum: Complex Solutions**

Out of curiosity, I sought complex solutions and found two, plus their complex conjugates.

```
tst = λ /. FindRoot[g[λ], {λ, 300 + 100 I}, WorkingPrecision -> 55, 
    Evaluated -> False]
(* 238.2470380128362751886150009319777802016484715271720041 + 
   5.046719683312651069843507113048343649792611971592912802 I *)
```

The corresponding eigenfunctions, computed as before, are plotted using  `ReImPlot`.

[image]

[image]

Another is

```
(* 440.9005698861846836113482607553640570450827531146712965 + 
   3.720425991419978280520680668723839826268342762230923495 I *)
```

Additional complex `λ` seem likely for larger `Re[λ]`.  I attempted to find complex `λ` for `Re[λ] < 100` but without success.

**Fourth Addendum: Modified Boundary Conditions**

In a comment below, the OP asked assistance for modified boundary conditions, `w1` instead of `w0` vanishing at `z = 0` asnd `z = 1`, and `u1` changed to

```
m = 1.495; theta = -0.78;
bc = Rationalize[{u2[0] + m theta u1[0] == 0, 
  u2[1] + m theta/(1 + theta) u1[1] == 0}, 0]
```

For convenience, redefine `var` as

```
var = {u0[z], w1[z], j1[z], ϕ0[z], u1[z], u2[z], u3[z], w0[z], j0[z], ϕ1[z]};
```

Then, the definition of `g` is changed to incorporate the new boundary conditions.

```
g[λt_] := Module[{v = Rationalize[λt, 0]}, Do[
  bc0 = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, 10], n + 5 -> 1];
  bc0 = ReplacePart[bc0, 5 -> First[SolveValues[bc[[1]], u1[0]] /. u2[0] -> bc0[[6]]]];
  a[n] = Flatten@NDSolveValue[{eq /. λ[z] -> v, 
    Thread[(var /. z -> 0) == bc0]}, {var[[;; 4]] /. z -> 1, 
    bc[[2, 1]]}, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {n, 5}];
  -10^-19 Det[{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]}]]
```

and plotted.

```
Plot[g[λ], {λ, -500, 500}, PlotRange -> {-8, 6}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 3, ImageSize -> Large, 
  AxesLabel -> {λ, "Det"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

By inspection, the change in boundary conditions has no impact on the `λ = -2` eigenvalue.  Some others, determined as before, are

```
(* λ -> -17.0804038779156676304536707040 *)
(* λ -> -60.1390404619194112940862825698 *)
(* λ -> 45.4674271506238708342777922448 *)
(* λ -> 86.0968951335092628679561771189 *)
```

Computing these eigenvalues took as long as a minute each.  As before, it is necessary to define

```
WorkingPrecision -> 55, MaxSteps -> 50000
```

in `g` to compute corresponding eigenfunctions.  An example is

```
tst = λ /. FindRoot[g[λ], {λ, -18, -16}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 55, Evaluated -> False, Method -> "Brent"]

NullSpace[Transpose[{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]}]] // Flatten
bc0 = Join[ConstantArray[0, 5], Rationalize[%, 0]];
bc0 = ReplacePart[bc0, 
  5 -> First[SolveValues[bc[[1]], u1[0]] /. u2[0] -> bc0[[6]]]];
NDSolveValue[{eq /. λ[z] -> Rationalize[tst, 0], 
  Thread[(var /. z -> 0) == bc0]}, var, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 55];

Plot[Evaluate[%[[;; 5]]], {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Head /@ var[[;; 5]], 
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], {.7, .1}]]
Plot[Evaluate[%%[[6 ;;]]], {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Head /@ var[[6 ;;]], 
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], {.7, .1}]]
Join[N[%%%[[;; 4]] /. z -> 1], 
  {N[bc[[2, 1]] /. ({u1[1] -> %%%[[5]], u2[1] -> %%%[[6]]}) /. z -> 1]}]
```

[image]

[image]

```
(* {-4.74378*10^-11, -1.11753*10^-6, 1.12926*10^-6, -1.15817*10^-7, -1.02345*10^-7} *)
```

The final line shows that the new boundary conditions are well satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful method. It works fine. However, I have a query. Can it be used when the coefficients are a function of the variable (in my case z)? I have a problem with those types of coefficients as well. The problem with NDSolve is it requires an extra condition on the solution to determine the eigenvalue.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, please notice the typo: The OP has `w1[z] == w0'[z]` . Your answer uses `w1[z] == w0[z]`

Comment: @Akku14 Thanks for catching the typo.  It was an error in transcribing the code to the answer, so the rest of the answer is correct.

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA As requested, I have added a solution using `NDSolve` instead of `DSolve`.

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA  And, now the corresponding eigenfunctions.

Comment: +1 a long time ago, but it would be helpful to me to have some idea of how long your computations take. I find this problem to be intractable for the amount of time I would spend on Mma.SE.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The symbolic solution is quite slow, which I partially circumvented with `AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3`.  The numerical solution is both faster and more accurate.  The computation in the second addendum takes about a minute.  This is true both for the specific eigenvalue shown and for several others.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you so much. Sorry for a late reply I got stuck somewhere. But this such as nice work. I will work with this and experiment with it. Thank you once again.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Hello. I have one different boundary condition. Instead of u1[z]==0 on z=0,1 I have u2[z]+m theta/(1+z theta)u1[z]=0 on z=0,1.  With that BC w1[z]==0 on z=0,1 instead of w0[z]. So, what I have done, I have replaced the second variable in var with u2[z]+m theta/(1+z theta)u1[z]. But the code is not working right now. How we fix it?

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA So that I am sure that I understand, you wish to replace `{u1[0]==0. u1[1]==0, w0[0]==0, w0[0]==0}` by `{u2[0]+m theta u1[0]==0, u2[1]+m theta/(1+ theta) u1[z]==0, w1[0]==0, w1[0]==0}`, with `m` and `theta` constants.  Is that correct?  If so, the procedures I gave above will work with only minor changes.  What are the values of the two constants?

Comment: @bbgodfrey That is correct. I have mad the chances, see if they are correct.
`
var = {u0[z], 
   u2[z] + 
    m theta/(1 + z theta) u1[z], 
   w1[z], u3[z], w0[z], 
  u1[z]};
var1 = {u0[z], u2[z], w1[z], 
   u1[z], u3[z], w0[z]};
g1[\[Lambda]t_] := 
 Module[{v = Rationalize[\[Lambda]t, 0]}, 
  Do[bc0 = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, 6], n + 3 -> 1];
   a[n] = 
    NDSolveValue[{eqnn /. \[Lambda] -> v, 
      Thread[(var /. z -> 0) == bc0]}, 
     var1[[;; 3]] /. z -> 1, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {n, 
    3}];
  Det[{a[1], a[2], a[3]}]]

`

Comment: @bbgodfrey and then 
`
NullSpace[Transpose[{a[1], a[2], a[3]}]] // Flatten;
bc0 = Join[ConstantArray[0, 3], Rationalize[%, 0]];
NDSolveValue[{eqnn /. \[Lambda] -> Rationalize[tst, 0], 
   Thread[(var /. z -> 0) == bc0]}, var1, {z, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 55];

`

Comment: @bbgodfrey m=1.495, theta=-0.78

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA Thanks for the information.  Your modifications as written may not have the desired effect.  I shall review them in detail late today or tomorrow morning.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you so much.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Please suggest the amendments. Thank you.

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA  Sorry for the slow response.  I have your requested solution, but a local internet outage means that I can upload it only very slowly.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you so much. It looks perfect. I have a query though, will it be working for all parameters or is there any limitation? I was playing around with the method but I observed that for some parameters, the NDSolveValue as well as other functions (such as NDSolve) fail to give a solution. So, either something happens to the system of equations or it is a numerical issue for those parameters. I haven't checked it yet but if you have any comments on this please share. Thank you once again.

Comment: @bbgodfrey What can be used as a replacement to SolveValues? I have an older version of Mathematica and it doesn't have that function.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I mean it is giving some result which I think is correct and it is working fine on your mathematica and I accept the answer. I was just asking if there any limitations to it and that since I have an old version of mathematica I don't have SolveValues so if you could suggest a similar function, it would be great. I accept your answer, it is a great way and I have been playing around with your method, it works nicely. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7):

### Update

As mentioned by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269503/linear-odes-with-ndsolve/269504?noredirect=1#comment672334_269504) and by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269503/linear-odes-with-ndsolve/269504?noredirect=1#comment672682_269504), the code I had proposed below only returns a trivial constant solution, as the following indicates:

```
Through[sol1[[1, All, 2]]["ValuesOnGrid"]] // Chop

(* Out:
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {20.00000000000000000000000 + 1.000000000000000000000000 I, 
  20.00000000000000000000000 + 1.000000000000000000000000 I, 
  [...]
  20.00000000000000000000000 + 1.000000000000000000000000 I, 
  20.00000000000000000000000 + 1.00000000000000000000000 I}}
*)
```

---

Replacing your original `Subscript` expressions helped a lot. Once those were removed, your original code produced an error from `FindRoot`, suggesting that a higher working precision could be needed. After some trial and error, a `WorkingPrecision -> 25` setting seems to work.

In the following code I also replaced your machine-precision constants (e.g. 0.04) with arbitrary-precision ones (e.g. 4/100), and combined equations and boundary conditions for clarity.

```
eqandbc = {
   j1[z] + 10 u1[z] + (-4/100 - 2/100 λ[z]) w0[z] + 2/100 w1'[z] == 0,
   (101/60 + λ[z] (2 + λ[z])) u0[z] + λ[z] ((2 - 1/2 λ[z]) u2[z] -
       250 w1[z] - 25 ϕ0[z] + 25 ϕ1[z] + 1/2 u3'[z]) == 0,
   100 u1[z] + ϕ1'[z] == 50 u3[z] + (2 + λ[z]) ϕ0[z],
   (2 + λ[z]) j0[z] == 50 w1[z] + j1'[z],
   u1[z] == u0'[z], u2[z] == u1'[z], u3[z] == u2'[z],
   ϕ1[z] == ϕ0'[z], w1[z] == w0'[z], j1[z] == j0'[z],
   
   u0[0] == 0, u0[1] == 0,
   u1[0] == 0, u1[1] == 0,
   w0[0] == 0, w0[1] == 0,
   j1[0] == 0, j1[1] == 0,
   ϕ0[0] == 0, ϕ0[1] == 0,
   λ'[z] == 0, u2[1] == 0
 };

sol1 = 
  NDSolve[
    eqandbc, {u0, w0, λ}, {z, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {
      "Shooting", 
      "StartingInitialConditions" -> {λ[0] == 20 + I}, 
      "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}
    }, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 25
  ]
```

[image: screenshot of the InterpolatingFunction solutions obtained from NDSolve]

Comment: Thank you so much. So, basically I need to set working precision to get it working and it will work for other bcs as well.

Comment: @GAURAVMAURYA That's likely, although performance may sometimes depend on the exact boundary conditions. But just try and see.

Comment: I noticed that the value of `λ` returned by your computation was essentially identical to your initial guess, `λ[0] == 20 + I`.  So I tried other initial guesses, and the code again returned the initial guess, which seems suspicious.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you.

Comment: As @bbgodfrey hinted, this this does not appear to be an effective solution. The solution produce is in effect the trivial (zero) solution, which would be apparent if the answer showed the plots. Zero is a solution for every proposed eigenvalue λ, but it is not an eigenfunction or a solution to the eigenvalue problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are both right, thank you for pointing it out. I added a note to the answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You are right, thank you for pointing it out. I added a note to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, if the comment was a little direct. I tried something like this (increased working precision), but you posted first. Actually, I thought the OP's trick of adding `λ'[z] == 0` shouldn't work, but it seemed to. So I thought I'd try a `MatrixExp` way and ran into trouble (condition numbers on the order of, not 46, but $10^{46}$!), which made me doubt everything, mine, yours, and @bbgodfrey's way. I'm still not satisfied, but running a trial takes too long.

Answer (score 4):

I have a package for solving eigenvalue boundary value problems using the Compound Matrix Method with the Evans function, which I'll use here. The package is available on [my GitHub](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod) (which has a notebook with examples), more details are in my other [answers to questions here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod), and a good introduction to the method is in [this pdf](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/%7Exl/FYB-background.pdf).

```
Needs["PacletManager`"] 
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", "Site" -> 
 "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Basically the Compound Matrix Method takes an $n$ by $n$ eigenvalue problem of the form $$\mathbf{y}' = A(x, \lambda) \cdot \mathbf{y}, \quad a \leq x \leq b, \\ B(x,\lambda) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}, \quad x=a, \\ C(x,\lambda) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}, \quad x=b,$$ and converts it to a larger system of determinants that satisfy a different matrix equation $$ \mathbf{\phi}' = Q(x, \lambda) \mathbf{\phi}.$$
This removes a lot of the stiffness from the equations, as well as being able to also remove the exponential growth terms that dominate away from an eigenvalue.

This is quite similar to bbgodfrey's solution of finding the determinant, but is more numerically stable.

I've taken your equations back to a natural form, without the first order substitutions, including just using $u, w, j, \phi$. The following function will sort all that out for you.

```
eqns = {j'[z] + 10 u'[z] + (-4/100 - 2/100 λ) w[z] + 2/100 w''[z] == 0, 
        (101/60 + λ (2 + λ)) u[z] + λ ((2 - 1/2 λ) u''[z] - 250 w'[z] - 
          25 ϕ[z] + 25 ϕ'[z] + 1/2 u''''[z]) == 0, 
        100 u'[z] + ϕ''[z] == 50 u'''[z] + (2 + λ) ϕ[z], 
        (2 + λ) j[z] == 50 w'[z] + j''[z]};

bcs = {u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0, u'[0] == 0, u'[1] == 0, w'[0] == 0, 
   w'[1] == 0, j'[0] == 0, j'[1] == 0, ϕ[0] == 0, ϕ[1] == 0};
```

We write the system in the matrix form $\mathbf{y}' = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, with the function `ToMatrixSystem`:

```
sys = ToMatrixSystem[eqns, bcs, {u, j, w, ϕ}, {z, 0, 1}, λ]
```

Then we use the "Evans Function", an analytic function whose roots correspond to the eigenvalues of the original system, reducing the problem to finding roots of a smooth function of one variable.

We can evaluate this function at a point, for instance $\lambda = -3$:

```
Evans[-3, sys]
(* -4.41549*10^-10 *)
```

This value is not zero, so $\lambda = -3$ is not an eigenvalue.

We can plot this function, and see that it is smooth, with a (double) root around 2:

```
Plot[Evans[\[Lambda], sys], {\[Lambda], -5, 0}
```

[image]

And we can use `FindRoot` to find a few roots:

```
FindRoot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, -3}]
(* {λ -> -2.} *)
FindRoot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, -15}]
(* {λ -> -14.5244} *)
FindRoot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, -100}]
(* {λ -> -134.338} *)
```

(This isn't exhaustive by any means, just a few that I found immediately).

I'm not sure why these is different to bbgodfrey's values though, I haven't dug into that. Perhaps I have made a mistake with the equations.

This method should work with coefficients as functions of $z$. I know it isn't Mathematica, but I would also say that I found the MATLAB plugin [chebfun](https://www.chebfun.org/) to be excellent for this kind of problem. As requested, a scrap of chebfun MATLAB code for a 10th order system (my MATLAB skill is very limited, I've taken some old code and removed constants but can't test this still works).

```matlab
% Assign the equation to two chebops N and B such that N(u) = lambda*B (u).
dom = [0 1];
N = chebop(@(x,u1,u10,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9) [diff(u1)-u2-u7-u9;diff(u2)-u3;diff(u3)-u4;diff(u4)-u2-u3-u6-u7-u9;diff(u5)-u6;diff(u6)-u4-u5;diff(u7)-u8;diff(u8)-u2-u7-u8-u9;diff(u9)-u10;diff(u10)-u2-u7-u9-u10], dom);
B = chebop(@(x,u1,u10,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9) [0.*u1;0.*u2;0.*u3;u1;0.*u5;0.*u6;0.*u7;1.*u7;0.*u9;1.*u9], dom);

% Assign boundary conditions to the chebop.
N.bc = @(x,u1,u10,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9) [u2(0); u3(0); u5(0); u8(0); u10(0); u2(1); u3(1); u5(1); u8(1); u10(1)];

%% Setup preferences for solving the problem.
% Create a CHEBOPPREF object for passing preferences.
% (See 'help cheboppref' for more possible options.)
options = cheboppref();
options.discretization = 'values';

%% Solve the eigenvalue problem.
[V, D] = eigs(N, B, k, options,'SM');
D = diag(D);
```

Comment: Thank you for this function. I have a query. What if there resultant values are complex numbers? I mean, you have only plotted the real part.

Comment: The Evans function is in general a function that maps from the complex plane to the complex plane. If you have entirely real values in your system (including boundary conditions) and give a real eigenvalue *I think* that the Evans function will be real if I remember correctly. But you can give e.g. `Evans[1+I,sys]` and it will give you a complex value, and `FindRoot` can find complex values.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the examples that I include in the github, i.e. file `CMMExamples.nb` from https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod . I have some examples of complex valued systems and eigenvalues there.
Note that you can have complex eigenvalues even given an entirely real system, I just think that if you try a real value of $\lambda$ then $E(\lambda)$ will be real if the system is real.

Comment: thank you so much. The method works fine to find the eigenvalues. But when I try to use the found eigenvalues in NDSolve to find the eigenvectors, it doesn't work. If you know the reason, please share. Thank you once again.

Comment: I have added some `chebfun` code that may be useful to you, although I can't test it. My package doesn't easily give you the eigenvectors I'm afraid. It is tricky to set that up for the general case, so I have never got round to coding that up (if it is indeed possible).

Comment: Thank you for the `chebfun` code. I am trying to use it for my work but some error is coming. Could you please look at it?

Comment: dom = [0,1];
opr = chebop(@(y,u,b,s) [-10*4^2*(1+y*0)^(-1.495)*5^2.*s./(50^2*0.001)+4^2*u+(1.495*0^2.*u./(1+y*0).^2)-(1.495^2*0^2*u./(1+y*0).^2)+1j*4^2*2*1.495*0*(1+y*0)^(-1.495)*50^2.*u./(4*2*50*0.001*(1+y*0))+4^2*(1+y*0).^(-2*1.495)*5^4.*u./(50^2*0.001^2)-2*1.495*0*diff(u,1)./(1+y*0)-1j*4^3*(1+y*0)^(-1.495)*5^2.*diff(u,1)/(4*2*50*0.001)...
    +1j*4*2*(1+y*0)^(-1.495)*5^2.*diff(u,1)/(2*50*0.001)...
    +1j*2*2*(1+y*0)^(-1.495)*5^2.*diff(u,1)/(2*50*0.001)-diff(u,2);...
    0.001*b+1j*5*2*u+0.001*diff(b,2)/4^2;-u./(1+y*0)+...
    1e-5*(-4^2.*s+1j*(1+1.495)*0.*s./(1+y*0)+diff(s,2))], dom);

Comment: oprlam = chebop(@(y,u,b,s) [(-1j*4^2*(1+y*0)^(-2*1.495)*5^4.*b/(5*2*50^2*0.001^2)...
    -4^2*u/0.001);b;s], dom);
opr.bc = @(x,u,b,s) [u(0); b(0); s(0);u(1);b(1);s(1)];

Comment: [V, D] = eigs(opr, oprlam);
D = diag(D);

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with the chebfun code, I don't have a license anymore, and my MATLAB skills were minimal anyway.

Comment: it is okay. no problem. Thank you for introducing me to chebfun, btw.